# How to multiply success_url in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

How to multiply `success_url` in Django view? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
class ResetPasswordRequestView(FormView):
    template_name = "registration/password_reset_form.html"
    form_class = PasswordResetRequestForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         form = self.form_class(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
              data = form.cleaned_data["email_or_username"]
         if self.validate_email_address(data) is True:
              success_url = '/reset/password/email/'
         else:
              success_url = '/reset/password/username/'
```

Comment: What do you mean with *multiply*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for each `if`  it's own `success_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [**`form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid), and return a `HttpResponseRedirect`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ResetPasswordRequestView(FormView):
    template_name = "registration/password_reset_form.html"
    form_class = PasswordResetRequestForm

     def form_valid(self, form):
         data = form.cleaned_data["email_or_username"]
         if self.validate_email_address(data):
              success_url = '/reset/password/email/'
         else:
              success_url = '/reset/password/username/'
         return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```